# Web Hosting Company that Allows custom SMTP servers, multi domains, .NET 4.0 and mixed hosting

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, hosting, asp.net, web-hosting

I am in search of a new Hosting company.

I currently use GoDaddy, but I've had enough with their service so i'm looking for a hosting company that can meet my criteria. Currently I have 10+ Websites that run off of a single hosting Plan, over half of which are Wordpress sites the others are ASP.NET 4.0 applications.

What I need:

- Support for SQL Server 2005 or Higher
- Support for MySQL
- Support for ASP.NET 4.0
- Support for Wordpress sites
- Ability to send Emails through
  GMail's SMTP Server
- Reliable (Speed, Uptime and
  Reputation)
- Multiple Application/Domain support
  under a single plan
- Ability to have domains elsewhere
  (Don't want to have to transfer
  domains in order to use the hosting)
- Inexpensive

Some of these are things I currently have and some of them are just on my list of needs. The big ones are the support for GMail's SMTP and then secondly speed. After switching to Grid Hosting on GoDaddy (only hosting that supports .NET 4.0) I noticed my Wordpress sites latency with the Google bot increased 10x.

Answer (score 0):

There are a good number of hosts out there that can handle what you're looking for. I personally work for Media Temple, and would be happy to address any questions you may have about our hosting.

I'd check out webhostingtalk.com to get a good idea of what people like.

Some other options would be rackspace, amazon, liquidweb, and hostgator.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it on forum. Webhostingtalk discuss many good provider. Godaddy seems very great, why do you want to find another hosting? You can visit asphostportal, hostgator, discountasp. But, if you're looking for the cheap price, you can go with asphostportal.com or hostgator.